# Check byte array contains byte array linq c#

Tags: linq, entity, contains

I need to check if an byte[] entity attribute contains an string. I tried everything I found but Linq seems to be pretty tight and doesn't allow me to use my custom methods so any idea?

I tried converting the string (Content) to byte array an then using a custom method check if my entity attribute (x.Document) contains the string converted(ContentBytes) with no success due to linq seems that it doesn't allow you to use methods it can't convert to plain SQL so I dont know how to get it.

```
using (GPC container = new GPC()) {
    var p = from t in ... 
        select t;
        if (Content != null) {
            byte[] ContentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Content);
            p = p.Where(x => this.CheckPatternInArray(x.Document, ContentBytes) == true);
        }

private bool CheckPatternInArray(byte[] array, byte[] pattern) {
    int fidx = 0;
    int result = Array.FindIndex(array, 0, array.Length, (byte b) => {
        fidx = (b == pattern[fidx]) ? fidx + 1 : 0;
        return (fidx == pattern.Length);
    });
    return (result >= pattern.Length - 1);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You might try filtering the smaller ("are these found") array; return true for found, false for not found (false returns from a filter method remove the value from the output).  After that, check the length of the output - if it's 0, all of the "are these found" values exist in the source.

Comment: Also, most of the linq methods (like `.where()` and `.select()`) are extension methods.  It's easy to build an extension method using IEnumerables.  Here's the "how to" from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-add-custom-methods-for-linq-queries

Comment: @theGleep thank you so muc, I think extend a method could be suitable, but I'm pretty new and it sounds like a charm for me, could you give me a more concret example please? I dont see who to implement it for .where as you say. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, for your goal (if I understand it correctly), an extension method is probably overkill.  Let me see what I can come up with for you, though.

Comment: Very kind of you @theGleep, I'm pretty lost and a help is very appreciated, I lost all day long with that in my job ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some *PSEUDO-CODE* to give an idea of what I'm thinking.  I make no promises that it will compile, much less run.  But it should point you in the right direction for your original question.

I declare 4 arrays; one that has the values we want to check for, and three test arrays.  Then I run the expression against each array to show what the output would be.

```C#
char[] toCheck = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

char[] hasAll = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
char[] hasSome = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
char[] hasNone = {'e', 'f', 'g'};

// verify the linq expression works by comparing against the different arrays
char[] foundList = toCheck.Except(v => hasAll.indexOf(v) >= 0);
// foundList.count == 0

foundList = toCheck.Except(v => hasSome.indexOf(v) >= 0);
// foundList.count == 2

foundList = toCheck.Except(v => hasNone.indexOf(v) >= 0);
// foundList.count == 0
```

Comment: I feel my self worse that in the begining of the post, I dont understand sorry, but many thanks for your effort, maybe anothet guy could show me an easy way to do it.

Comment: My apologies ... I guess this is one of those "I've learned to think it, but not really explain it"..

Comment: I revised the answer to be a little more clear about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In the comparison can you do other way around? I mean, if you know the encoding then u can convert the x.Document to string. Then comparing the string will be very easy.

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
string s = enc.GetString(x.Document);
```

You don't need o write a extension function.

Comment: Hi @Shuvra, as soon as I try to include something that it can't be converted to plan SQL linq throws an exception. I tried something like u tell me but same problem and I thinkg conver de whole bynary document is worse regarding performance. Thanks any way.

Comment: is your x.Document is a image file? if it is can you give me extension?

Answer (score 0):

As for creating an extension method, here is one I made to make it easier to inspect the progress of a linq expression:

```js
    public static class LinqUtilities
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Inject this in your Linq chains to inspect each item as it is processed.  
        ///     
        ///     The item can be changed during the "tap" operation, but a new item cannot be created
        ///     
        ///     Use this for logging or for in-line audits (summaries, secondary list creation...) or anything else that catches your fancy!
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="this"></param>
        /// <param name="tapper">function to observe the current object</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<T> Tap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Action<T> tapper)
        {
            foreach (var item in @this)
            {
                tapper(item);
                yield return item;
            }
        }

    }
```